# Wave equation interpretation for different physical quantities

Tags: physics, wave-equation

I've been working on a project to do with scattering of acoustic waves and one of the first steps towards finding my solutions was to derive the wave equation:

$$
\nabla^2 U = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial t^2}
$$

I "know" that U in this case can be any physical quantity (velocity, pressure, etc) but I don't really understand this intuitively.

I derived the equation from Navier-Stokes for pressure (and hence density) so I get those two. But why is this valid for velocity too? I'm currently using it for the velocity field for my solutions and I think missing this bit of conceptual understanding is really holding me back!

Comment: Not *every* quantity obeys the wave equation; it has to be [motivated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Derivation_of_the_wave_equation). In this case, $U$ (or $u$ on Wikipedia) isn't a velocity field at all; it's a displacement amplitude.

Comment: What do you mean by in this case? This form of the wave equation applies to all sorts of physical quantities from my understanding, including velocity fields and displacement amplitudes.

Comment: What if I try $U=t^2$? That clearly doesn't solve the wave equation.